# How to format CSV file to display like a table in html

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I found this code online (credits to owner, sorry i forgot the website) and I'm just trying to add style to it (im just starting to practice my html and im trying csv format to display) but it's not showing. The only thing I was able to do is add some borders and change the text color.

What I want to do is for it to display in table format where the table lines appear when it uploads. I did a lot of research but i still cant figure it out. I also tried using Table td and tr but it didnt work and im not sure where to put it in the code. Maybe im just too dumb so forgive me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  

    <script type="text/javascript">

            function loadFile(o)
            {
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function(e)
                    {
                        showDataFile(e, o);
                    };
                fr.readAsText(o.files[0]);
            }

            function showDataFile(e, o)
            {
                document.getElementById("data").innerText = e.target.result;
                document.getElementById("data").style.color="blue";
                //document.getElementById("data").style.borderRight="thick 
 solid #0000FF";
                //document.getElementById("data").style.columnRuleWidth = 
 "thick";
                //document.getElementById("data").style.columnRuleStyle = 
 "solid";

            }
        </script>

 </head>
 <body>
    Select file to read <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this)">
    <pre id="data"></pre>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: use a parser, for example: `https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Generate-A-Table-From-A-CSV-File-CSV-Parser/ `

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the answer, I was hoping not to use a parser. just format the display of csv base on html stuff. is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function loadFile(o)
{
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(e)
        {
            showDataFile(e, o);
        };
    fr.readAsText(o.files[0]);
}

function showDataFile(e, o)
{ 
  var getCSVData = e.target.result;
  var rows = getCSVData.split("\n");
  var html = '<table border="1">';
  rows.forEach((data, index) => {
    html += "<tr>";
    var value = data.split(",");

    html += "<td>" + value[0] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + value[1] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + value[2] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + value[3] + "</td>";

    html += "</tr>";
  });
  html += '</table>';
  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = html;
  document.getElementById("data").style.color="blue";
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
</head>
<body>
    Select file to read <input type="file" onchange="loadFile(this)">
    <pre id="data"></pre>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Just what I'm looking for. Thank you so much. Hey man, is it possible to describe what each line does under the script file if you can? I just want to understand the whole flow of that code. I understand some but not all..